# How to get gradle build time?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to get the statistics of gradle build time with type of build for all my colleagues who have worked with me in our repository/project.

I see this way:

1. Add the first step for all buildTypes which save start build time in the local file (txt I think)
2. Add the last step for all buildTypes which get from local file time, calculate the difference between now and time from a local file, and send to my server.

But as I think Gradle is a very functional tool and I could just not notice this feature in the list of default functions.

How you made this functional in your project?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/performance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

- gradle plugin with `BuildListener`
- track start time: `(gradle as GradleInternal).services[BuildStartedTime::class.java].startTime`
- track end time `BuildListener::buildFinished`
- calculate and send to our server

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a [Gradle Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/).  This will give you a detailed report about you build including times. It's viewable online and easily shared.